# Get Google Meet recorded minutes

Tags: google-api, google-workspace, google-meet

I'm trying to get the total Google Meet recording minutes for the organization. In the [Google Meet Quality tool](https://support.google.com/a/answer/9204857) I can see that there is a field named "Recording Status" and "Length".

Ideally, I would like to get a list of all Google Meets that have "Recording Status: Uploaded" and then use the information in the field "Length" to get the total minutes.

I could not find anything related to that in the [Google Meet API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/appendix/usage/customer/meet) documentation. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks